# How to remove everything after % in dataframe and merge deleted data into a new data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a rather odd question. Not sure if this is possible, but if it is it would be a workaround for a problem I am having. I am creating the following table:

```
library(janitor)
firsttable <- tabyl(df, Essay, Grade) %>%
  adorn_percentages("col") %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 1) %>%
  adorn_ns()
```

```
 Essay         A         B         C          D
     N 30.0% (3) 37.5% (3) 70.0% (7) 93.8% (15)
     Y 70.0% (7) 62.5% (5) 30.0% (3)  6.2%  (1)
```

As you can see, the variables are in character format, and include a percentage and count in parentheses. I would like to:

1. remove the % sign and everything after it
2. save what I remove and merge it into another data frame (with the same dimensions as the initial table) after

So the above table would become:

```
 Essay  A     B    C    D
     N 30.0  37.5 70.0 93.8
     Y 70.0 62.5  30.0  6.2
```

And I would save the the % sign and values that follow it to be merged into a data frame `b` of the same dimensions:

```
b <- tabyl(df, TrueFalse, Color)
```

```
TrueFalse  B G R Y
     FALSE  7 5 1 1
      TRUE 11 5 9 5
```

So the final table would be:

```
TrueFalse  B          G       R         Y
     FALSE  7% (3)   5% (3)   1% (7)    1% (15)
      TRUE 11% (7)   5% (5)   9% (3)    5% (1)
```

I understand that in this example this would produce totally incorrect percentages for the final table, but all I'm looking for is the ability to remove everything including and after the percentage sign then merge it into the cells of a data frame of the same dimensions. It's an odd question, I know.

Any help would be appreciated!

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Grade = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D"), Essay = c("Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "N", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"Y", "N", "N", "N"), Color = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "G", 
"G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "R", "R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), 
    TrueFalse = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-44L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `readr::parse_number` `across` the columns except the 'Essay'

```
library(dplyr)
firsttable %>%
   mutate(across(-Essay, readr::parse_number))
# Essay  A    B  C    D
#    N 30 37.5 70 93.8
#    Y 70 62.5 30  6.2
```

---

Inorder to get the second output, extract the number inside the bracket along with the bracket from the columns after `select`ing out 'Essay', then use `map2` (from `purrr`) to `paste` (`str_c`) with the corresponding columns of 'b' (except the 'TrueFalse')

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
firsttable %>% 
     select(-Essay) %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ str_extract(., "\\(\\d+\\)"))) %>%
     map2_dfc(b %>%
             select(-TrueFalse), ., str_c, sep='% ') %>%
     add_column(TrueFalse = b$TrueFalse, .before = 1)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  TrueFalse B       G      R      Y      
#  <lgl>     <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  
#1 FALSE     7% (3)  5% (3) 1% (7) 1% (15)
#2 TRUE      11% (7) 5% (5) 9% (3) 5% (1)
```

---

Or use `Map` in `base R`

```
 b_new <- b
 b_new[-1] <- Map(function(x, y)
   sprintf('%d%% %s', x, sub(".*\\s+", "", y)),  b[-1], firsttable[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the values, `core`, from the tabyl object and combine it with `b`:

```
core <- attr(firsttable, "core")
replace(b, -1, Map(sprintf, "%d%% (%d)", b[-1], core[-1]))
##      TrueFalse       B      G      R       Y
##          FALSE  7% (3) 5% (3) 1% (7) 1% (15)
##           TRUE 11% (7) 5% (5) 9% (3)  5% (1)
```

The table of percentages can be recreated from the `core` values:

```
setNames(cbind(core[1], 100 * proportions(as.matrix(core[-1]), 2)), names(core))
##   Essay  A    B  C     D
## 1     N 30 37.5 70 93.75
## 2     Y 70 62.5 30  6.25
```

or alternately the strings could be extracted from firsttable and converted to numeric:

```
replace(firsttable, -1, Map(function(x) as.numeric(sub("%.*", "", x)), firsttable[-1]))
##  Essay  A    B  C    D
##      N 30 37.5 70 93.8
##      Y 70 62.5 30  6.2
```